# How can I wait for a dynamodb update table or ACTIVE state using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am changing the table, for example the capacity settings using boto3
then I need to wait for its completation

I would prefer a solution using `boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('MyTable')` instead of dynamodb client.

Comment: Updating the table is an asynchronous operation (like creation of the table) as mentioned in boto3 docs (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_table). 
Unlike the way you use a waiter to check for table existence, boto3 (currently) doesn't have waiters to poll to check the status of the table. 
You could probably use describe_table() to check the status at regular intervals and either use SNS or SES to notify you the change.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to make your program wait until the **Table Update** is finished:

```
def table_status_checker(self):
    while True:
        table = self.__dynamodb.Table('table_name')
        response = table.meta.client.describe_table(
            TableName='table_name'
        )
        print(response['Table']['TableStatus'])
        if response['Table']['TableStatus'] == 'ACTIVE':
            break
```

There is small **lag** between *Console UI* and this *describe_table(...)*.

Therefore, don't get confused with the Console UI Table Status.