# Check if DynamoDB - table has been updated, or is currently being updated, with AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, insert-update, dynamodb-queries

Even though I skimmed through the [official docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html), I couldn't find a simple example showing how to check this.

**Context:**

One or more files are uploaded into a S3-bucket. This triggers a data preprocessing lambda-function, which then puts these changes into certain DynamoDB-tables. Later on, these tables need to be further processed.
In order to prevent the associated lambda-function to scan all DynamoDB-tables, there should be a way of knowing which tables have been updated.

---

**Desirable solution:**

Naively, there should be a way of doing the following via the Python SDK boto3:

```
for _table in entire_table_list:
    if is_updated(_table):
        .. trigger further processing
    elif is_being_updated(_table):
        .. do something else, maybe wait till the table update is done
```

As I have not found something akin to this, I'd be delighted to know how to handle this situation best.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such functionality in DynamoDb, you'll need to build this yourself. You didn't share the details of your access patterns, but it sounds like you need to design your data model to accommodate fetching unprocessed items, or maybe fetching items by some timestamp.  There's also DynamoDb streams, which is useful for post processing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does it help anything that AWS Glue-Jobs and Glue Tables/Data Catalogs are involved? In other words, is it alternatively possible to get the desired functionality of the OP with AWS Glue Tables?

Comment: I came across some similar DynamoDB - requests here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984680/12298276  -> does something like the mentioned `response['Table']['TableStatus'] == 'ACTIVE` - queries help in my case?`